# Every value in request.POST is a list

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having problems because every value in request.POST is inside a list. So whenever I do this:

```
MyForm(request.POST)
```

None of the validations pass because they are expecting strings and not lists. And the error messages are of this sort:

```
[u'13/04/2000'] is not a valid date
```

Is there a setting or something i need to change so i can just pass request.POST to a form? I really don't want to do something like request.POST.get(..) for every field.

Ok here is my form:

```
class FormAddCourse(forms.Form):
    career = choice_field(Career)
    assignature = choice_field(Assignature)
    start_date = forms.DateField(label = spanish('col_name', 'start_date', True),
                                 help_text = "Formato: dd/mm/aaaa")
    end_date = forms.DateField(label = spanish('col_name', 'end_date', True),
                               help_text = "Formato: dd/mm/aaaa")
    day_choices = [('Mo', 'Lunes'), ('Tu', 'Martes'), ('We', 'Miércoles'), ('Th', 'Jueves'),
                   ('Fr', 'Viernes'), ('Sa', 'Sábado'), ('Su', 'Domingo')]
    days = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label = spanish('col_name_plural', 'day', True),
                                     widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                     choices = day_choices)
    length_choices = (
        ('S', spanish('choices', 'semesterly', True)),
        ('Y', spanish('choices', 'yearly', True)),
        )
    length = forms.ChoiceField(label = spanish('col_name', 'length', True),
                               widget = RadioSelect,
                               choices = length_choices)
    hours = forms.CharField(widget = HiddenInput,
                            max_length = 300,
                            validators=[validate_hours])
```

And here is my view:

```
def add_course_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = FormAddCourse()
        c = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('crud/courses/add.html', c, RequestContext(request))
    elif request.method == "POST":
        try:
            hours = get_hours(request.POST)
            form_data = {'hours': hours}
            form_data.update(request.POST.copy())
            form = FormAddCourse(form_data)
            if form.is_valid():           # This thing never passes
                career = form.cleaned_data['career']
                assignature = form.cleaned_data['assignature']
                start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
                end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
                days = form.cleaned_data['days']
                length = form.cleaned_data['length']
                hours = form.cleaned_data['hours']
                credits = calculate_credits(valid_hours)
                # alter database
                # course = Course.objects.create(career=career, assignature=assignature, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, days=days, length=length, credits=credits, hours=hours)
                if u'submit_another' in request.POST:
                    # Submit and add another
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, u"El curso ha sido guardado. Agregue otro.")
                    return redirect('crud.views.add_course_view')
                else:
                    # Submit and end
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, u"El curso ha sido guardado.")
                    return redirect('ssys.views.homepage')
        except FieldError as e:
            # return user to complete form with fields already filled
            pass
```

As for the validation functions, the only custom one is validate_hours which is actually the only one that passes because I add in the hours manually to the form_data.

Ok i figured what the problem is, I can append to request.POST.copy() but i can't append it to a dictionary. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You're clearly doing something odd here. You shouldn't be accessing request.POST values at all. Please post the validation functions at least.

Answer (score 3):

`request.POST` is a [QueryDict, which is dictionary-like class but not dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).

You could try

```
form_data = request.POST.copy()
form_data.update({'hours': hours})

#instead of
form_data = {'hours': hours}
form_data.update(request.POST.copy())
```

But, according to your code, the `hours` is fetched from `request.POST` also. Then why not merely use the form to process all fields? If you have trouble to do it in the form or there is any special logic consideration, you could make it clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be instantiating the form as follows:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    pass
```

No other code should be needed to get basic form validation in Django. If you need to add values to `request.POST` then consider creating hidden input fields and including the intended values in the form already.